# Can I use nvim --remote to replace nvr?

Tags: neovim, fish

I'm using `neovim-remote`/`nvr` to avoid nested instances of nvim when using the integrated terminal. This is the code:

```bash
# config.fish
if set -q NVIM
    # Avoid nested neovim instances with neovim-remote
    set -gx EDITOR "nvr --remote-wait"
    alias nvim nvr
else
    set -gx EDITOR nvim
end
set -gx VISUAL $EDITOR
```

It works well. A pain point is temporary files; it's why I use `--remote-wait`. If I don't, the program that is expecting to read the temporary file (e.g. git commits, `Alt-E` to edit fish's command line in `$EDITOR`) breaks.

This works, but I know neovim has a built-in `--remote` feature, and I'd like to use that to avoid the dependency. This is the configuration:

```bash
# config.fish
if set -q NVIM
    # Avoid nested neovim instances with nvim --remote
    set -gx EDITOR "nvim --server $NVIM --remote"
    alias nvim $EDITOR
else
    set -gx EDITOR nvim
end
set -gx VISUAL $EDITOR
```

However, this doesn't work with temporary files. For example, git complains that the message was empty and aborts the commit. Fish doesn't modify the prompt. From what I can gather, the difference is that `nvr --remote-wait` blocks until all buffers are deleted but `nvim --remote` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible with plain neovim: https://neovim.io/doc/user/remote.html#E5600

> Vim supports additional functionality in clientserver that's not yet
> implemented in Nvim. In particular, none of the "wait" variants are supported
> yet.

I found this issue which requests the `--remote-wait` feature. You could follow that to be notified of updates.